# Xpath Contains(.,'text') how to use text as custom command

Tags: generics, xpath, command, cypress, contains

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('xpath', (text: string) => {
  return cy.xpath('(//span[contains(.,text)]/following::td)[1]')
})
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for this.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('xpath', (text: string) => {
  return cy.xpath(`(//span[contains(.,${text})]/following::td)[1]`)
})
```